# ASP.NET - How to save a List Collection to DB using Stored Procedure?

Tags: asp.net, list, collections

I have a List Collection:

```
 List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    Person p1 = new Person();

    p1.FirstName = "Nikos";
    p1.LastName = "Kantzelis";
    p1.Email = "nikolaosk@hotmail.com";
    p1.Height = 1.78m;
    p1.Weight = 88.5m;


    Person p2 = new Person();

    p2.FirstName = "James";
    p2.LastName = "Rowling";
    p2.Email = "jamesr@hotmail.com";
    p2.Height = 1.98m;
    p2.Weight = 98.25m;

    Person p3 = new Person();

    p3.FirstName = "George";
    p3.LastName = "Graham";
    p3.Email = "graham@yahoo.co.uk";
    p3.Height = 1.88m;
    p3.Weight = 81.5m;

    people.Add(p1);
    people.Add(p2);
    people.Add(p3);
```

Now I want to save the values inside this List Collection to some of my tables in DB using a stored procedure.

Please advise.

Regards,
Pawan

Comment: What DB are you using? What data access technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something fancier, but you can do something like this:

```
foreach (Person person in people)
{
    //example code
    //save each person in the list to the database
    SavePerson(person.Name, person.Age, ...); 
}
```

If you'd rather, you can also do it with LINQ like this:

```
//example code
//save each person in the list to the database
people.ForEach(person => SavePerson(person.Name, person.Age, ...));
```

Comment: This would be the best approach in my opinion.  There isn't really a clean way to send an entire list to the DB server and have the DB server iterate the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks looks like a good way. But if I have 100 person information in People List, this will cause 100 calls to DB. Is that a good way to do? Also, is there any way to serialize the people object into XML and send that XML to DB using some Stored Procedure. If there is any such way to send XML, is that considered a good method? Thanks,
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is SQL 2005 (or is it 2008) and above, you could serialize the list of objects to XML, then pass the whole XML blob to the SP in a parameter then use MSSQL's XML query capabilities to parse the XML and insert the data into the table.

Sort of a `INSERT INTO Person SELECT * FROM XML`

That would allow a single SP call and it could be wrapped in a transaction within the SP (rather than crossing process boundaries).

Comment: Every time I see a select * I want to scream and burn buildings down.